# What type of tape is used to seal vapor barrier seams?

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

If I was installing vapor barrier in Canada, I'd use [Tuck® Contractors Sheathing Tape](http://www.cttgroup.com/cantech/en/details/135/).  However, after a trip to the local Home Depot (USA), I came up empty in my search for Tuck Tape.

I did find [Tyvek® Tape](http://www2.dupont.com/Tyvek_Weatherization/en_US/products/residential/resi_seam_tape.html), which is used to seal the seams of [Tyvek® HomeWrap®](http://www2.dupont.com/Tyvek_Weatherization/en_US/products/residential/resi_homewrap.html).

Can Tyvek tape be used as a stand in for Tuck tape, or are there more appropriate products available?

Comment: here I was thinking that duct tape was the goto tape for everything

Comment: Looks like canadian tire sells Tuck tape

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I too, was in search of Tuck Tape at Home Depot / Lowe's and couldn't find it. When I asked a salesman about it, they didn't understand what I was looking for.

When I said I wanted to seal the edges of vapor barrier, they told me to use the Tyvek tape, the same one you found.

Duct tape won't cut it; it's too porous. We used the Tyvek and it's worked well so far.

Don't use it on hard wood floors as painter's tape; it'll rip the polyurethane right off of the floor (lesson learned).

> It is the opinion of the Canadian Construction Materials Centre (CCMC) that “Tuck® 205-02 Contractor's
>   Sheathing Tape / DuPontTM Tyvek® Tape”, when used as a sheathing tape in accordance with the conditions and limitations stated in Section 3 of this Report, complies with the National Building Code 2005:
>
> [PDF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CD4QFjAA&url=http://www.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/ccmc/registry/pdf/11955_e.pdf&ei=Mw01T4aMMa7F0AGWrKi1Ag&usg=AFQjCNF4U2ye9cxVNr-rIa1u3IR4gOFvrg)

Comment: for the record I was making a joke

Comment: @ratchetfreak for sure; but too many people think duct tape solves everything. There's tape for duct work (which isn't duct tape), plastics, drywall, etc... Could you imagine someone using duct tape for taping seams on drywall? That would be funny.

Comment: Can you provide any data to back up the HD associates claims that this is the proper product to use?

Comment: Yes, actually, I can. Answer modified.

Comment: Avtually The statement from the CCMC refers to exterior sheathing NOT interiror vapor barrier. The poster was asking about interior vapor barrier.

Answer (score 0):

I love how people take this vapor barrier stuff to the edge of infinity.

I remember when I took my contractor license test... 18 inch overlap doesn't even require sealing with tape.  If your concrete, or subfloor, or really any space is putting out enough moisture vapor to get past a simple overlap of poly then you have a much more serious problem than the correct tape.

Almost all of the "stucco tape" and "sheathing tape" I found is for temporary hanging of plastic.  The Intertape brand has one that says it's specifically for sealing vapor barriers so that's what I used.  But to be honest... I felt like duct tape works better.  I found some duct tapes that were rated to bond 20 yrs.  That Intertape bonded well, but not as sticky and nasty as duct tape.  I called on manufacturer of "sheathing tape" they said bond is only good for 2 years MAX.

The very best thing to do is call the manufacturer tech line for the wood/laminate or other covering and MAKE SURE you are talking to a tech guy and NOT a rep/sales rep.  Ask for the nerdy guy, he has all the legitimate answers.

I've installed LOTS of different products and many of the instructions for those different products give conflicting advice.  Your investment is safe if you follow the instructions for YOUR product.

PS.. one of the manufacturers specifically says to seal the seams with good ole duct tape.  :-)